# CodeIgniter Form Validation callback to model from config rules?

Tags: forms, codeigniter, validation, codeigniter-3

My User_model have a public method called is_unique_email($email). This method checks if a user has a uniqe mail adress with some status flag checks. This is also the reason why I can't use the standard is_unique validation rule from CodeIgniter.

I'm using a form_validation.php with config array for my validation rule groups. My question is: How can I call the model method for checking the new user's e-mail address? I searched and tried so many things, but nothing work. My preferred call would be with | pipe separator.

Like: `trim|required|max_length[70]|valid_email|`<~ here comes the model callback ~>

Is there any solution for this callback or is there no way and I have to extend the Form_validation system library?

I'm using CodeIgniter 3.1.7.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

Because I've always done things via extending the `form_validation` library I forgot about this:

https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks-your-own-validation-methods

and this (anonymous functions):

https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callable-use-anything-as-a-rule

Might be better for you. When in doubt, always read the docs ;)

---

Yes you can extend the `form_validation` library. In `application/library` make a `MY_Form_validation.php` and have it extend CI's as such:

```
class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {
```

then in it you can do something like this:

```
/**
 * Checks to see if bot sum is valid 
 * e.g. equals the session stored values
 * 
 * @param int $sum
 * @return boolean
 */
public function valid_bot_sum($sum) {
    $generated = $this->CI->session->bot_first_number + $this->CI->session->bot_second_number;
    if ($generated !== intval($sum)) {
        $this->set_message('valid_bot_sum', 'Invalid bot sum.');
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

and now your function can be accessed via pipe separators as any native `form_validation` validation function. Just be sure to set the message on false as I've done, otherwise you will get an error. You can access the CI instance like so `$this->CI`.

In your case you can either migrate the function from the model into this file, or you can call it by loading the model in the function and calling the function and just testing to see if it evaluates to true/false and handling as above.

Comment: I've tried the second (Callable: Use anything as a rule) from the docs. But nothing of the things work in the config form_validation.php :(

Comment: Code is meant to be in controller, not in config. 
You can instantiate config/rules in constructor then extend it with callable function.

Comment: At the moment I have extended the CI_Form_validation class. First I tried to handle this with a __call class Method. Later with an model_validator[User_model->is_unique_email] and model_validator($value, $action) method. But always I try to call $this->CI->$action an error occoured. Only after I create a static public method with exact $this->CI->User_model... call, it works. But it's - I think so - not the best solution at all to duplicate all validate methods from model again. So I'm open for better solutions :)

Comment: your question was regarding whether or not it was possible to  add additional form validation rules. I showed you it was. The comments aren't for adding on to the question or additional debugging, if you have another question or a question related to the implementation of said methods make another question. The docs are incredibly clear, especially: "Callbacks: Your own Validation Methods" which I think would work well for you and they've explained it better than I can.

Comment: My question was if there is a solution for calling models directly from the config validation rules. At the moment I don't have a solution for this. In this case my question was, if there is no way to call a model form config validation rules - so the documentation is complete or if there is a possible way, but it's also documented the set rules method way. I also know the documentation content and alternative way to extend validation class.

Comment: Completely missed the line "form_validation.php with config array for my validation" by that you mean you aren't doing `$this->form_validation->set_rules('some_field', 'Some field', valid_email|some_callback` but you are doing: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#setting-rules-using-an-array / https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#creating-sets-of-rules? Why don't you just migrate the rules locally (you use them too often?)? In such a case my above method is the only way to really do it (and from comments your doing it as well).